# How to get post data variables from textbox after submition a form in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, form-validation

How do I get data of post variables ? Like if I post form with post method then I can get it with `$_POST` or not

this is my form

```
<form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo $this->getDeclineUrl(); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" id="decline" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>" onclick="namet()" />
  </form>
```

in phtml file i have added a form with post method i want to data variable of this form

I am using code this on same page

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost('field_name');
```

but i am not getting data

Comment: that's the way you should get it, unless you have an error somewhere. Maybe you send the form via GET. Maybe your field have a prefix and the name of the input looks like `prefix['field_name']` ?

Comment: @Marius where should i write this code on same page or controller... i am passing form via post i am not getting about get

Comment: You need this in the controller that handles your request.

Answer (score 1):

Use for phtml

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('field_name');
```

in your case

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('message');
```

Comment: i am using this

Comment: form action on same page

Comment: No problem with when you post then use it like `if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('message')): 
echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('message');
endif;`

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by :

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('field_name');
```

Comment: i am using above code but its not working for me ...i am working it on same phtml file am i right

Comment: Your form action is on same page?....You also try to make a controller and send request there.

Comment: this is my form <form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo $this->getDeclineUrl(); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" id="decline" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>" onclick="namet()" />
  </form>

Comment: i have action on same page

Comment: how to make controller and send request there

Comment: inspect and check what URL is in action that is <?php echo $this->getDeclineUrl(); ?>

Comment: You can refer this URL :
https://www.pierrefay.com/en/magento-training/create-a-controller-tutorial.html
and in form action you have to pass controller URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50016/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-ram-systematix).

Answer (score 1):

You can check what you getting in post by

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($postData);
```

and then you can get the field value by key of that array like

```
$postData['key'];
```

Comment: this is my form code

Comment: <form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo $this->getDeclineUrl(); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" id="decline" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>" onclick="namet()" />
  </form>

Comment: what are you gettting from `<?php echo $this->getDeclineUrl(); ?>` ?

Comment: this is same page url

Comment: i am getting textbox value on same page but i want to call it on shopping cart page

Comment: if <?php echo $this->getDeclineUrl(); ?> retuen nothing or function not define then you have to define it first or u can use $this->getUrl('router/controller/actionname'); and u get your value in your action by $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();